# How to verify the text in IE status bar with Selenium?

Tags: selenium

There are some text which should display in IE status bar like Last Refresh time. I wanted to extract the value. Is there any way to verify this in Selennium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium does not have any method to get the text from the status bar. You may invoke the below AutoIT script from your selenium script to retrieve the text displayed in the status bar.

Here is what you can do:

1. Download AutoIT
2. Use below script to get the status bar text:

   ```
   //instead of "Untitled - Notepad" use title of the web page
   WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad", "", 30) 
   Local $hWnd = WinGetHandle("Untitled - Notepad")
   //the part number would be 1 instead of 2
   Local $sText = StatusbarGetText("Untitled - Notepad","",2)
   ConsoleWrite($sText)
   ```
3. Save the above script as .au3 file and compile it to get the .exe file using AutoIT
4. Invoke the exe file from your selenium script

**Explanation**:
WinWaitActive - Pauses execution of the script until the requested window is active.

```
WinWaitActive ( "title" [, "text" [, timeout = 0]] )
```

**Parameters**
title = The title/hWnd/class of the window to check.

text[optional] = The text of the window to check. Default is an empty string.

timeout [optional] Timeout in seconds if the window is not active. Default is 0 (no timeout).

More Information on the functions here - https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/

Comment: WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad", "", 30) . Can you explain this parameter.?? what is empty and what is 30??

Comment: 30 seconds is the timeout and the empty string is the text which is an optional field. I have updated the answer. You can refer the link to read about the functions used in AutoIT.

Comment: There is a library named AutoITx4java, in case you are looking for a java solution- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302726/automate-through-a-remote-desktop-using-selenium-and-autoit/29313250#29313250