# Automate through a remote desktop using Selenium and AutoIt

Tags: java, selenium, autoit

I want to automate certain tasks which needs it to go through [Remote Desktop Connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Remote_Desktop_Connection).

I will share the code which I wrote till now.

```
public class MainClass
{
  static WebDriverWait  wait;
  static WebDriver driver;
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
    driver.get("https://mysite");
    WebElement submit_element=driver.findElement(By.id("Log_On"));
    driver.findElement(By.id("Enter user name")).sendKeys("my_username");
    driver.findElement(By.name("passwd")).sendKeys("my_password");
    submit_element.click();
    driver.findElement(By.id( "folderLink_0")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id( "folderLink_2")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
    driver.findElement(By.id("idCitrix.M")).click();
    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
  }
}
```

The line of code

```
`driver.findElement(By.id("idCitrix.M")).click();`
```

opens the remote desktop in a new window.

The line

```
`System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());`
is retrieving the same code in both places.
```

I believe this cannot be done solely by Selenium. By browsing through the Internet I learnt it is possible to do this using [AutoIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt).

How can I do it?

Comment: How did the answer so far work out for you? As far as I know, even though AutoIt automates Windows, it might not work against Windows objects through a remote desktop session. To deal with that you need AutoIt running on the actual remote desktop computer you are connecting to, not AutoIt on the web browser computer you are using remote desktop (client) with.

Answer (score 3):

Selenium can be used for the parts that are automating your web browser whereas AutoIT should be used for automating Windows applications (in your case, its probably logging into the remote machine).

This link provides good information on how to use AutoIT alongwith Selenium: http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/

Here is what you have to do:

Download/install AutoIT
You will be able to create .au3 scripts using **AutoIT** **SciTe Editor**
Compiling the .au3 script will give you a .exe file 
Then you can invoke the .exe file from your Selenium script using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\AutoIt\AutoItTest.exe");
```

You can get the properties of a window using the **AutoIT Window Info (x86) or (x64)**. Example, title / status bar of a window.

AutoIT also has **Au3 Recorder** so that you can record your actions that are related to the remote desktop.

Below is a sample script that automates Http authentication:

```
WinWaitActive("Web page title","","10")
If WinExists("Web page title") Then
Send("userid{TAB}")
Send("password{Enter}")
EndIf
```

Below script gets the text present in the status bar of Notepad:

```
WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad", "", 30) 
Local $hWnd = WinGetHandle("Untitled - Notepad")
Local $sText = StatusbarGetText("Untitled - Notepad","",2)
ConsoleWrite($sText)
```

I hope this information helps!

**Update**:
Upon further searching, found this library AutoITx4Java - https://code.google.com/p/autoitx4java/

1. Download Jacob, AutoIT  (refer the above link)
2. Add jacob.jar and autoitx4java.jar to your library path.
3. Place the jacob-1.15-M4-x64.dll file in your library path.

**Sample Code**

```
File file = new File("lib", "jacob-1.15-M4-x64.dll"); //path to the jacob dll
System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());

AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
String notepad = "Untitled - Notepad";
String testString = "this is a test.";
x.run("notepad.exe");
x.winActivate(notepad);
x.winWaitActive(notepad);
x.send(testString);
Assert.assertTrue(x.winExists(notepad, testString));
x.winClose(notepad, testString);
x.winWaitActive("Notepad");
x.send("{ALT}n");
Assert.assertFalse(x.winExists(notepad, testString));
```

Comment: Hi...Thanks for your time..But can it not be done using AutoIt libraries in eclipse?

Comment: FYI, an alternate way to integrate Selenium with AutoIt using only Selenium API can be found here: https://github.com/daluu/AutoItDriverServer